# scala map java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found elegant

Tags: scala, dictionary, exception, pattern-matching

How can I retrieve the element from the map in elegant scala style?
A try catch doesn't seem right. 
Is a check with contains the best option?

Trying to pattern match won't catch the exception.

```
case class SomeClass(first: Int, second:String)
val someClass = SomeClass(1, "foo")
val myMap = Map("firstKey" -> Map("secondKey" -> someClass))
myMap(("col1"))("XXX") match {
    case s:String => s.first
    case _ => 0
  }
```

Comment: Perhaps, you want: `myMap.get("firstKey").flatMap(_.get("secondKey")).fold(0) { case s: String => s.length }`

Comment: This seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use for comprehension for it

```
val length = for(col1 <- myMap.get("col1");
                 str <- col1.get("XXX")) yield str.first
val res = length.getOrElse(0)
```

Comment: I think this solution is cleaner. And more readable than the first comment.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you find defaults more elegant, but they're better than catching exceptions.

```
val myMap = Map("firstKey" -> 
                 Map("secondKey" -> "someValue").withDefaultValue(""))
                            .withDefaultValue(Map().withDefaultValue(""))

myMap("firstKey")("secondKey").length  // res0: Int = 9
myMap("firstKey")("secondK").length    // res1: Int = 0
myMap("firstK")("secondKey").length    // res2: Int = 0
```